# Multiple POST to One Endpoint Django

Tags: django

I have an endpoint `/homepage` in my django app that renders an HTML page. This page has several forms that each make a POST request to the `/homepage` endpoint. How can I decipher which POST request is being sent to the `/homepage` endpoint?

Or, is it better to make and endpoint like `/api` that has sub-endpoints for each of the POST requests in the page?

Thanks!!

Comment: You can add a `name=''..."` to the submit buttons of the forms. But it is often better to specify an separate endpoint for each functionality. This makes it easier to maintain the software.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem thank you for your response. Do you suggest to create an api app and make a ```/api``` endpoint and put those separate endpoints in there?

Answer (score 0):

It would be great if you consider Separation of Concern strategy and keep separate api end points for each form and make ajax call relevant endpoint on each submit and update the relevant elements according to ajax call response on homepage instead of reloading whole page would make your application more efficient and scalable.

Comment: Thanks for this answer! Would you be able to link an example of this being implemented for reference?

Comment: Surely, Can you please share more details about your task?

Answer (score 0):

If you are relying on form-based validation and you want any errors returned to the user and displayed on the homepage, one of the following approaches is probably best.

As mentioned in the comments, you can set `name` and `value` attributes on the submit button in each form on your page, then check for that value when processing the POST:

**template:**

```html
<button type="submit" name="action" value="add">Submit</button>
```

**views.py:**

```py
def homepage(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        action = request.POST.get('action', None)
        if action == 'add':
            # do something
```

If that doesn't suit your needs, you could append parameters to the form action URL and process it in a similar way:

**template:**

```html
<form action="{% url 'homepage' %}?action=add" method="post">
```

**views.py:**

```py
def homepage(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        action = request.GET.get('action', None)
        if action == 'add':
            # do something
```

However, if you don't need to display errors to the user on the homepage, go with separate endpoints for each form.

Comment: Thanks for the response!! What do you mean by: "However, if you don't need to display errors to the user on the homepage, go with separate endpoints for each form."

Comment: No problem. A typical way of handling an invalid form submission is to display the form again complete with the submitted details and an explanation why it isn't valid. If you would like these details/errors to appear on the same page where the form was originally submitted, submit to your homepage endpoint.